# Codeigniter Pagination issue with query string

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I have a pagination script that i made in codeigniter, and here's my script

```
/*---product_pagination----*/
        $total_row = $this->autoload_model->get_data_from_table("td_model,td_country","*",
                                                                "td_country.country_id = td_model.model_country
                                                                 AND td_model.model_id > 0
                                                                 ORDER BY td_model.model_username")->num_rows();

        echo $total_row;
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        //$start_row= $this->uri->segment(3);
        $segment_3 = $this->uri->segment(3);
        if($segment_3 == '')
        {
            $start_row = 0;
        }
        else
            $start_row = $_REQUEST['start_row'];
        if(isset($_REQUEST['per_page']))
            $perpage = $_REQUEST['per_page'];
        else
            $perpage = 2;
        if(trim($start_row) == '')
        {
         $start_row =0;
        }
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'model/show_model/?start_row='.$start_row;
        $config['total_rows'] = $total_row;
        $config['per_page'] = $perpage;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = "<div class='pagination'>";
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<span style='width: 80px; '>";
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</span>';
        $config['first_link'] = '<< First';
        $config['first_tag_open'] = "<span style='width: 80px; '>";
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</span>';
        $config['last_link'] = 'Last >>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = "<span style='width: 80px; '>";
        $config['last_tag_close'] = "</span>";
        $config['next_link'] = 'Next >';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = "<span style='width: 80px; '>";
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</span>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '< Prev';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = "<span style='width: 80px; '>";
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</span>';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data['all_model']=$this->autoload_model->get_data_from_table("td_model,td_country","*",
                                                                "td_country.country_id = td_model.model_country
                                                                 AND td_model.model_id > 0
                                                                 ORDER BY td_model.model_username")->result_array();
        $data['model_list']=$this->autoload_model->get_data_from_table("td_model,td_country","*",
                                                                "td_country.country_id = td_model.model_country
                                                                 AND td_model.model_id > 0
                                                                 ORDER BY td_model.model_username
                                                                 LIMIT $start_row, $perpage")->result_array();

        /*$this->product_model->products_fragment_by_category($cat_slug,$start_row,$perpage);*/

        /*----pagination ends------*/

       $this->load->view('header',$data);
       $this->load->view('header_lower');
       $this->load->view('model_list');
       $this->load->view('left_bar');
       $this->load->view('footer');
    }
```

the issue is that i am getting this url

```
http://localhost/ecam/model/show_model/?start_row=0&per_page=2

http://localhost/ecam/model/show_model/?start_row=0&per_page=4
```

why is that per_page getting extended to 2 4 6...

it seems that start_row value is getting as the per_page value;

Answer (score 1):

Note that "per_page" is the default query string passed, however can be configured using

`$config['query_string_segment'] = 'offset';//you change per_page param-name to offset`

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html

- per_page in query parameter is **offset**
- per_page in config is **limit**